# Why won't recursive generator work?

Tags: python, recursion, generator

I have a class where each instance is basically of a bunch of nested lists, each 
of which holds a number of integers or another list containing integers, or a 
list of lists, etc., like so:

```
class Foo(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.extend(
            list(1), list(2), list(3), range(5), [range(3), range(2)]
            )
```

I want to define a method to walk the nested lists and give me
one integer at a time, not unlike `os.walk`. I tried this:

```
def _walk(self):
    def kids(node):
        for x in node:
            try:
                for y in kids(x):
                    yield y
            except TypeError:
                yield x
    return kids(x)
```

But it immediately raises a stopiteration error. If I add a print statement to print each "node" in the first for loop, the function appears to iterate over the whole container in the way I want, but without yielding each node. It just prints them all the first time I call `next` on the generator.

I'm stumped. Please help!

Comment: is x an instance variable of your class (as well as a local variable)?

Comment: `return kids(x)` will give a `NameError`!

Comment: `self.extend(list(1), list(2), list(3), range(5), [range(3), range(2)])` makes no sense either. If you want to write pseudocode, that's fine, but don't make it look like real Python code!

Comment: Anyways, a very wild guess on what `kids` is supposed to do: Flatten a list of lists, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: Yeah, whoops, that code was gibberish. x was a typo--should have been self. Don't want to flatten nested lists though--don't want everything in memory. Just want one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you change `return kids(x)` to return `kids(self)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that is a simpler version of your `_walk` method that does what you want on an arbitrary iterable.  The internal `kids` function is not required.

```
def walk(xs):
    for x in xs:
        try:
            for y in walk(x):
                yield y
        except TypeError:
            yield x
```

This could be trivially adapted to work as a method on your `Foo` object.